# Apache Knox Ldap Integration failed

Tags: hadoop, ldap, bigdata, apacheds, apache-knox

I am using Apacheknox version 1.0.0. I have tried to authenticate knox uiusing Ldap user. I have tried with following changes in knox

```
 In ambari --> knox-->config-->Advanced topology           

            
<param>
<name>main.ldapRealm.userDnTemplate</name>
<value>cn=admin</value>
</param>
<param>
<name>main.ldapRealm.contextFactory.url</name>
<value>ldap://x.x.x.x:10390</value>
</param>
```

First Iam trying for single user only.I have tried different user search But no luck I am always getting same error like below.

```
2021-01-29 10:22:07,266 ERROR knox.gateway (KnoxLdapRealm.java:doGetAuthenticationInfo(206)) - Shiro unable to login: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error
 code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: Invalid authentication]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LDAP: error code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS` Means, three things, Username/password is incorrect or the account is locked. You are having this error for `Bind user`.

You need to verify you **systemUsername** and **systemPassword** in configured topology.

A tool `ldapsearch` can be useful to verify credentials for Bind user.

**main.ldapRealm.userDnTemplate** should be like following

```
<param>
<name>main.ldapRealm.userDnTemplate</name>
<value>cn={0},ou=hadoop,ou=personal,ou=accounts,dc=example,dc=com</value>
</param>
```

Comment: cn={0},ou=Users,o=xxxxxxx. in My case this is worked for me.